# how to remove whitespace from password validation in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, formik

In password field if I give "Password@345" its accepted and right but if I give "Password @ 345" its also accepted but its should not accepted because condition is there is no whitespace, how to remove the  whitespace  that if I type password with whitespace it should give error.

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
 import * as Yup from 'yup';
export default function DropDown() {
 const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    Password: Yup.string()
     .matches(
        "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#!@$%^&*()+=]).{8,20}$",
        `Should contains at least 8 characters and at most 20 characters\n 
        Should contains at least one digit\n 
        Should contains at least one upper case alphabet\n 
        Should contains at least one lower case alphabet\n
        Should contains at least one special character which includes !@#$%&*()+=^\n
        Should doesn't contain any white space`
        )
      .required('password is required'),
   
  });
  return (
    <>
     
     <Formik
       initialValues={{
         Password: '',
        }}
       validationSchema={SignupSchema}
       onSubmit={values => {
         console.log(values);
       }}
     >
       {({ errors, touched }) => (
         <Form>
           <Field name="Password" placeholder="type password" autoFocus="true" autoComplete="off"/>
           {errors.Password && touched.Password ? (
             <div style={{color:"red"}}>{errors.Password}</div>
           ) : null}
          
          <br/><br/>  
          
           <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
         </Form>
       )}
     </Formik>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should really split up your validation, each separate condition should be it's own validation test/message. As-is if any one condition fails you have no way of letting the user know which cases passed/failed and they may need to guess. Better to let user know exactly what failed requirements. ***K***eep ***I***t ***S***illy ***S***imple, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `yup` you can define multiple `match` on your schema, so in your issue, you can define a separate match to check if password contains `space` or not and then apply other validation terms. like below example:

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  Password: Yup.string()
    .matches(/^\S*$/, 'Whitespace is not allowed')
    .matches(
      '^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#!@$%^&*()+=]).{8,20}$',
      `Should contains at least 8 characters and at most 20 characters\n 
      Should contains at least one digit\n 
      Should contains at least one upper case alphabet\n 
      Should contains at least one lower case alphabet\n
      Should contains at least one special character which includes !@#$%&*()+=^\n
      Should doesn't contain any white space`
    )
    .required('password is required'),
});
```

Comment: In fact, each separate condition should be it's own validation test/message.

Comment: Yes, that's because I use a separate `match`.

Comment: No, this is a good start, IMO, I meant that each "Should...." should have it's own matcher. I left a more descriptive comment to OP above.

Comment: yes Saeed Shamloo its working fine

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are matching using `.` which also accepts whitespaces.

Use `\S` instead:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9#!@$%^&*()+=])\S{8,20}$
```

Note how all the lookaheads can be combined into one to make the regex shorter and easier to read.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gz3iux/5)